# How to view the list of c library functions in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, command-line, glibc, system-calls

I'm a newbie in `Linux` programming. I found that the way to view the list of system calls in `Linux` via command-line is: `man syscalls`

But now I want to view the list of `c library functions`, how can I do that? Which command will help me list the `c` library functions? And another question, where are system calls and `c` library functions manual pages located? Thank you.

Comment: I did, but it's an overview page, not the list of libc functions. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a giant list of the functions in libc. You might also try the glibc doc [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html).

Comment: +1 for the glibc link and the rest of @ElliotFrisch's comment. I visited [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html) and [libc(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/libc.7.html) hoping to find something concise, but both are brief and somewhat disappointing (yet perhaps worth reading for context).

Comment: Also note that "the library" is not well-defined; while libc is a good start and reasonably standard, many other libraries (X11, Boost, etc) are in widespread use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[System calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) man pages are located in the section 2 of the man pages, see [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), and their list in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Library functions man pages are located in the section 3 of the man pages, see [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html). There are [many](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/) of them (and most of them use some syscalls, but some don't need any syscalls e.g. [round(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/round.3.html)).

And some useful Glibc specific functions don't have man pages, for example [argp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html) functions.

As [Elliot Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch) commented, see [Gnu libc documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html).

BTW, you could use something else than GNU libc, for instance [musl libc](http://musl-libc.org/).

You should also read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

Read also the [Posix opengroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) documentation.

At last, Linux also have many very widely used libraries, like [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) and [gnu readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) for terminal I/O, and [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) or [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) for graphical user interfaces above [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) (both having a foundational library : Gobject+Glib for GTK, and QtCore for Qt, which is useful by itself outside of any GUI programs).

And [freecode](https://freecode.com/), [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/), [github](https://github.com/) and many other places mention many [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) libraries, most of them being developed on Linux. For instance [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) is a useful library giving you HTTP server abilities.

For databases, see [mariadb](https://mariadb.org/), [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/), [postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/), [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/gdbm.html), [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) etc... (and [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) for [JSON](http://json.org/) textual serialization)

BTW, your Linux distribution should give you a lot of development packages too. On Debian more than 200 packages match `lib*dev` package name (and some libraries have a development package named differently).

There are several good books about Linux programming, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238/what-is-the-best-book-to-learn-linux-system-programming)...

<sup>Be aware that Linux is mostly free-software friendly. Give attention to software licenses and their [compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_compatibility).</sup>

If possible, make your own Linux software project a free software, e.g. by publishing it with a license like e.g. [GPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) (early, even barely working, in [alpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Alpha) stage...) on some site like [github](http://github.com/) or [gitorious](https://gitorious.org/) or [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/) etc... You could get useful feedback.

You might consider coding in [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) (which can use C or C++ libraries easily). Notice that C++11 is really different from previous versions of the C++ standard. If you do, be sure to use a recent compiler, like [GCC 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/). You could even consider customizing GCC with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) if your software is complex enough to worth the effort.

Comment: By "where" are the man pages, did you mean the actual files?  Linux man has a -w option which will show you the path to the man page itself.

Comment: God just give an example not a book lol

Answer (score 2):

Both wikipedia and cppreference are good for this, as well as the documentation for the the libc you have (likely glibc).

For example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte

Answer (score 1):

The man-pages that should come with Linux also can be found at [man7.org](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html).

It provides various indexes ("long lists")  on the man-pages.

The current POSIX man-page index is here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/nfindex.html